# How do I make a directive use filtered HTML attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that builds a popup menu which automatically collects data from HTML. It is actually supposed to convert a set of Bootstrap carousel-compliant elements, into a list. A catch is that each `.item` carries an attribute with its string value filtered, as in:

HTML:

```
<div class="item" data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}">
   ...
</div>
```

When I link the directive to element, using this snippet:

```
.directive('sectionBuilder', function(){
    return {
        priority:100,
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var data = [];
            $('.carousel-inner > .item', '#carousel').each(function(i, el){
                data.push({k: i, v: $(el).attr('data-title')})
            });
        }
    }
})
```

I get a menu of raw, unprocessed strings used in HTML:

```
{{'My string' | myfilter}}
{{'My string 2' | myfilter}}
```

From what I understand, attrs.$observe applies to attributes of the element being bound to directive, but not the external elements.

How do I get angular to use the filtered strings? I tried setting priority to a extreme values, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-attr`, that would be more convenient solution. `ng-attr-data-title` will evaluate interpolation `{{}}` & create data-title attribute with value.

Instead of using `data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}"` use `ng-attr-data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}"`

**Markup**

```
<div class="item" ng-attr-data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}">
   ...
</div>
```

**Update**

As you are getting value like `{{'My string' | myfilter}}`, `{{'My string 2' | myfilter}}` with interpolation then you could use `$parse` or `$interpolate` service to evaluate them.

```
.directive('sectionBuilder', function($interpolate){
    return {
        priority:100,
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var data = [];
            $('.carousel-inner > .item', '#carousel').each(function(i, el){
                data.push({k: i, v: $interpolate($(el).attr('data-title'))})
            });
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, @pankjparkar. Unfortunately it does not work for me. Neither `$(el).attr('ng-attr-data-title')})` nor `$(el).attr('data-title')})` do the job.

Comment: are you rendering this element using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Nope. It is a single instance. The carousel slides that are providing the menu item strings are taken in the `$.each` loop

Comment: @nuton check my edit, you could take use of `$parse`

Comment: The clue was to use `$interpolate` instead. Thanks for help - marking your answer as the one that pushed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In your directive, you have to set **transclude** property to **true** and have to use html template with **ngTransclude** as attribute to process your default angular filter inside HTML tags.

For reference:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/angularjs/custom-directives.html

Comment: At first I thought: good catch - I forgot about transclude! But it did not work either. You mean I should add ng-transclude to each carousel slide?

Comment: i hope you have to include ng-transclude attribute to the <div class="item" ng-transclude data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}">
   ...
</div>

Comment: Works without a tiny bit of transclusion (neither js nor html). Remember though, that my directive does not output a template, it collects data for a drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've omit to compile html template.
Try

```
$compile('
    <div class="item" data-title="{{'My string' | myfilter}}">
       ...
    </div>
')
```